# iptables kernel module missing after upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 -> 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, kernel-modules, ubuntu-20.04

After a release upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 (focal), the iptables kernel module is missing:

```
root@server:~# iptables -L
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic
iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

I tried the following, but it did not fix the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall iptables
```

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure iptables
dkms autoinstall
```

linux-modules-extra is also installed

output of `ls -R /var/lib/dkms` is:

```
/var/lib/dkms:
dkms_dbversion  wireguard

/var/lib/dkms/wireguard:
1.0.20200611  kernel-5.4.0-42-generic-x86_64

/var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20200611:
5.4.0-42-generic  source

/var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20200611/5.4.0-42-generic:
x86_64

/var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20200611/5.4.0-42-generic/x86_64:
log  module

/var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20200611/5.4.0-42-generic/x86_64/log:
make.log

/var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20200611/5.4.0-42-generic/x86_64/module:
wireguard.ko
```

Any ideas how I can reactivate iptables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On my Ubuntu 20.04 installation the file `/lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_tables.ko` belongs to the `linux-modules` package, not `linux-modules-extra`. Reinstalling `linux-modules` should do the trick:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the extremely quick reply. That solved it.

Comment: In a more general way: `dpkg -S /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_tables.ko`